# How do I encapsulate an image in a shape?

Tags: swiftui

The following code snippet yields a `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Circle' with no arguments` error on the .clipShape() line. I've tried shuffling around the modifiers to no avail. Any suggestions for fixing? Thanks!

```
struct MedCircleImage: View {
    var image: Image

    var body: some View {
        image
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(periwinkle, lineWidth: 3))
            .frame(width: 86, height: 86)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

you did not define your periwinkle variable...unfortunately SwiftUI does not always show the "real" error

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var image: Image = Image("laguna")

    var body: some View {
        image
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 3))
            .frame(width: 86, height: 86)
    }
}
```